# Better handle logged_in and logged_out without showing wrong layout in iron-router

Tags: meteor, iron-router, meteor-blaze, spacebars

i'm trying to get a clean redirection to the login form if the user isn't logged in. This basically works but i often see my main layout which only logged in users should see. I only see it for a second then before the login screen is showing but i'm trying to get rid of this shortly "flickering" faulty page.

My router.js looks a bit like this:

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layoutPrimary',
  loadingTemplate: 'loading',
  waitOn: function() {
    if (Meteor.user()) {
      return Meteor.subscribe('messages');
    }
    else {
      return;
    }
  }
});

Router.route('/', {name: 'dashboard'});
Router.route('/login', {name: 'login'});
```

some more routes without anything special (some subscriptions). Now we check if the user is logged in. If not he shall be delivered a special layout containing only the login/register functions.

```
// require login on all routes
Router.onBeforeAction(function () {
  if(!Meteor.user() && !Meteor.loggingIn()){
    this.layout('layoutSlim');
    this.render('login');
  } else {
    this.next();
  }
});
```

then we're handling 404s and doing some functions for user check that are used in the routes above.

```
// 404 Handling
Router.route('/(.*)',function(){
  this.render('error404');
});

// Be sure the Meteor.user() exists when settings are loaded
var userIsLoaded = {
  ready: function() { return !!Meteor.user(); }
};

var userLoggedIn = function() {
  if (!Meteor.user() && !Meteor.loggingIn()) {
    this.stop();
    Router.go('login');
    return false;
  }
  else {
    return true;
  }
};
```

Any idea what i can do to avoid that shortly showing wrong layout? I also sometimes see the login screen when logged in - this is quite rare but it would be a better user experience if this wouldn't happen at all.

I'm not 100% sure if this is related to iron-router or probably an issue that could be handled by spacebars/blaze?

Thanks for helping,
Frank

Comment: @Heimi how did you ended solving this?

Comment: not yet. still trying around but don't have a solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the `subscribe('messages')` gets done, but the Meteor users collection not.

You can use the `currentUser` helper from `Accounts Package`

```
{{if currentUser}}
     <!-- show information here -->
  {{else}}
     <!-- Forbiden template or login template -->
{{/if}}
```